# Why can't F# infer the type in this case?

Tags: f#

Consider the following sample code where I have a generic type and 2 static member constructors that create a specialized instance of the said type.

```
type Cell<'T> = { slot: 'T }
with
    static member CreateInt x : IntCell  = { slot = x }
    static member CreateString x : StringCell = { slot = x}
and IntCell = Cell<int>
and StringCell = Cell<string>

// Warnings on the next 2 lines
let x = Cell.CreateInt 123
let y = Cell.CreateString "testing"
```

I think I have the necessary type annotations in place and yet F# gives me warnings. E.g:

`Warning 2   The instantiation of the generic type 'Cell' is missing and can't be inferred from the arguments or return type of this member. Consider providing a type instantiation when accessing this type, e.g. 'Cell<_>'.`

How can I make the warning go away?

Comment: Hint: you're using static members of a _generic_ type.

Comment: @ildjarn You should post that as an answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hinted by @ildjarn, `Cell` is a generic type and the compiler wants to know the type `'T` when calling the static member.

```
// Two ways to fix the compiler warning
let x = Cell<int>.CreateInt 123
let y = StringCell.CreateString "testing"
```

A way to avoid specifying `'T` is to move the create functions into a module.

```
type Cell<'T> = { slot: 'T }
type IntCell = Cell<int>
type StringCell = Cell<string>
module Cell =
    let createInt x : IntCell = { slot = x }
    let createString x : StringCell = { slot = x }

let x = Cell.createInt 123
let y = Cell.createString "testing"
```

However, since you specify the desired type in the function name anyway, the following syntax may be preferred.

```
type Cell<'T> = { slot: 'T }
with
    static member Create (x : 'T) = { slot = x }
type IntCell = Cell<int>
type StringCell = Cell<string>

let x = IntCell.Create 123
let y = StringCell.Create "testing"

// or simply
let z = Cell<float>.Create 1.0
```

Thanks to @Vandroiy for pointing out the missing type constraint in my `Create` method and for his answer that shows how the compiler can infer `'T` for the generic type `Cell` when it can be determined by the static method being called.

Comment: Thanks! Just a note, the module solution doesn't work for me since my real example relies on optional arguments

Comment: @rgrinberg and cadull: I do not think this is good design. If you replace the last line with `Cell<string>.Create 1.0`, it is just as "valid". (See my answer)

Comment: Why do people continute to upvote this? The second solution, the one the OP is apparently goin with, has serious problems! The problem isn't limited to the generic type. `IntCell.Create "hello"` also compiles without problem.

Comment: @Vandroiy, thanks - I've corrected this now. Before posting I had a type constraint, but removed it as a simplification without realising the method had become generic. I had assumed it was automatically associated with `'T`.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler cannot determine the generic parameter `'T` of the methods `CreateInt` and `CreateFloat` because it is unrelated to the methods' return types. In the question, it is valid to write:

```
Cell<float>.Create 1.0 // useless type annotation to remove warning
```

However, you can just as well write

```
Cell<string>.Create 1.0 // Trollolol
```

To avoid this, you need to make sure the factory can only produce the type it is called on. When declaring a factory on a generic type, use a type annotation to equate the generic argument of its return type with the generic argument of the type it is called on.

In my opinion, the complicated formulation adds to the confusion. You can achieve the desired effect with

```
type Cell<'T> =
    { slot: 'T }
    static member Create (x : 'T) = { slot = x }

let x = Cell.Create 123
let y = Cell.Create "testing"
```

*Note the type annotation for `x` that equates the factory's input type with the generic parameter of the `Cell<>` type!*

Edited to address the comment:

As is, the types `IntCell` and `StringCell` serve no purpose; they are just a less readable form of `Cell<int>` and `Cell<string>`. From a comment to this answer, I understand that these types should be exposed instead of `Cell`. As far as I know, this is not possible if they are defined as in the question, since type abbreviations have at most the accessibility of the type they abbreviate.

This is a reasonable design choice: if a type is generic, it should accept all valid generic type arguments. If `IntCell` and `StringCell` add specialized implementation, the usual way is to compose them of the appropriate instantiation of the Cell type and their specialized features. Then, the Cell type is allowed to have a more restricted accessibility than the specialized types.

Comment: The cell type was just an example. In my original design the generic type is meaningless and should not be constructed. Only the 2 specializations are exposed

Comment: @rgrinberg I don't think this would work; the specializations are type abbreviations and thus will be limited by the accessibility of the Cell<> type. See the edited answer.

Comment: Cool answer, I didn't know you could omit the generic specification when using the type in this way; I'm used to seeing code like `Cell<_>`. The original question does not exhibit the issue in my answer since it declares the return type of the create functions. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: @cadull great! I removed the reference to the problem in your answer (and the down-vote, of course). I'll leave this answer here; can't hurt to have two formulations.