# F# static member, instantiation of generic type missing--possible bug?

Tags: generics, f#, static-members

I'm writing my own version of the Writer monad, for self education. I'm trying to have some generality (but not trying to achieve/approach that fully via statically resolved type parameters or other workarounds).

My first version gets a warning:

```
type Writer<'w, 'a> = | Writer of 'a * List<'w>  with 

  static member sum (l1:'w list) (l2: 'w list) = l1 @ l2

[<AutoOpen>]
module WriterMonadMod = 

  module Writer =
      let apply (mf:Writer<'w, ('a -> 'b)>) (ma:Writer<'w, 'a>) : Writer<'w, 'b> =
          let (Writer (f, l1)), (Writer (a, l2)) = (mf, ma)       
          let b = f a
          Writer (b, Writer.sum l1 l2)  // Warning, on "Writer.sum", 
//Instantiation of generic type missing, can't be inferred.
```

Okay, that makes sense. Which static sum do we want? For which particular instantiated types of Writer? I don't know if I can ignore this warning or if it could bite me eventually. So I try to put a type argument on "Writer" before ".sum"--but now that causes an error:

```
          Writer (b, Writer<'w, 'b>.sum l1 l2)  //Error, on "<'w, 'b>",
//unexpected type arguments.
```

This confuses me because it looks like the syntax in another SO answer for [Why can't F# infer the type in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093812/why-cant-f-infer-the-type-in-this-case) (`Cell<float>.Create 1.0`; which works for me, no error, no warning; and trying non-generic types does not change my problem.)

So I fool around with names, distinguishing the type from it's value constructor, adding "T"--and now it fixes iself!:

```
type WriterT<'w, 'a> = | Writer of 'a * List<'w>  with 
//...
    static member sum (l1:'w list) (l2: 'w list) = l1 @ l2

[<AutoOpen>]
module WriterMonadMod = 

    module WriterT =
        let apply (mf:WriterT<'w, ('a -> 'b)>) (ma:WriterT<'w, 'a>) : WriterT<'w, 'b> =
            let (Writer (f, l1)), (Writer (a, l2)) = (mf, ma)       
            let b = f a
            Writer (b, WriterT<'w, 'b>.sum l1 l2)  //No warning, no error.
//(With "T" distinguishing the type name from value constructor.)
```

Does this make sense? Why apparently the usual practice of using the same name for type and constructor seems to cause an ambiguity here?

(Side notes: "T" is not a great choice I guess, since this isn't a monad transformer. And the reason for all the type annotations on apply was to debug.)

Update due to Tomas's answer:

Curiously, to me, this also works to avoid the error, and the warning. *Whildcards* serve to resolve the *ambiguity* warning!?

```
    module WriterT =
        let apply (mf:WriterT<_,_>) (ma:WriterT<_,_>) : WriterT<_,_> =
            let (Writer (f, log1)), (Writer (a, log2)) = (mf, ma)       
            let b = f a
            Writer ( b, WriterT<_,_>.sum log1 log2 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "unexpected type arguments" error in the second case is very confusing (perhaps even a bug). I think what is happening here is that the compiler first resolves `Writer` as the case name and then reports the error when it finds the type arguments. It then realises you are actually referring to a type and changes the plan. Renaming the type (in your last example) resolves this ambiguity.

Another way to resolve this is to add the `RequireQualifiedAccess` attribute, which will hide the union case behind the type name, so you have to write `Writer.Writer` and the first name refers to the type:

```
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type Writer<'w, 'a> = | Writer of 'a * List<'w>  with     
  static member sum (l1:'w list) (l2: 'w list) = l1 @ l2

module Writer =
  let apply (mf:Writer<'w, ('a -> 'b)>) (ma:Writer<'w, 'a>) : Writer<'w, 'b> =
      let (Writer.Writer (f, l1)), (Writer.Writer (a, l2)) = (mf, ma)       
      let b = f a
      Writer.Writer (b, Writer<_,_>.sum l1 l2)
```

Now you can type `Writer<_, _>.sum` and it works because the type reference is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for looking Tomas. I guess I should submit a suggestion. And this seems like a good occasion for me to try looking into the compiler myself and see if I can debug this myself, which I've been meaning to try to learn.

Comment: Now it strikes me in your code: that the warning inability to infer the Writer type for static ".sum" goes away with a _wild card_ type annotation!? I see that changing all type args on `WriterT` to `<_,_>` in `apply` still avoids the warning. Seems odd that wildcards can repair an ambiguity. But maybe that's because I don't really understand how type inference works.